# what i need to do to support popup in the chrome.experimental.sidebar

Tags: google-chrome

I have few question about chrome.experimental.sidebar

1.Do I have control over the width ?

2.Facebook connect did not work in the chrome.experimental.sidebar,I did not see the facebook popup ,What i need to do to support popup in the chrome.experimental.sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar API is an highly experimental feature of Google Chrome. Also according to it's [Issue (51084)](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51084), no one is actively developing this feature. I recommend to don't rely on it. It's marked as milestone-x which means API definitely won't be graduated until Chrome 14.

1. According to [this documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.sidebar.html), extensions cannot control width of the sidebar.
2. Sidebar content is a restricted area of the browser. Extensions only can navigate. Also extensions only allowed to navigate trough extensions' local html pages.